# How to Print WebElement variable name in Selenium Webdriver POM Model?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Class A:

```
...
@FindBy(css="locator")
public static WebElement variableName;
```

Class B:

```
...
System.out.println("WebElement name is "+ I WANT TO PRINT variableName here);
```

Comment: if you have: public static WebElement loginButton ; you want to print "WebElement name is loginButton"  ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct!!!